# OOP java Stack Overflow from overridden method

Tags: java, oop, methods

This is a beginners OOP question, that probably has many answers, but I have not been able to find them. I will try to ask here in the hope that someone can explain or point me in the right direction.

As an example consider my MWE, where `RightTriangle` extends `Rectangle` that extends `Shapes`. The methode `semiPerimeter()` is implemented by calling `perimeter()`.

All is well for the `Rectangle`, where both `perimeter()` and `semiPerimeter()` works. The problem is the `perimeter()` methode of `RightTriangle` which overrides the `Rectangle` `perimeter()`. When running the test, I get a StackOverflowError, because `semiPerimeter()` calls `perimeter()` that in turn calls `semiPerimeter()`.

Why does the `super.semiPerimeter()` call not use the `perimeter()` from the rectangle super class?

---

### **MWE**

**Shapes.java**

```
package ShapesPackage;
public abstract class Shapes {
    public abstract double perimeter();
    public double semiPerimeter() {
        return perimeter() / 2;
    }
}
```

**Rectangle.java**

```
package ShapesPackage;
public class Rectangle extends Shapes {
    public double perimeter() {
        return 2 * (3 + 4); //2*(length+height)
    }
}
```

**RightTriangle.java**

```
package ShapesPackage;
public class RightTriangle extends Rectangle {
    public double perimeter() {
        return super.semiPerimeter() + 5;  //half the rectangle perimeter plus some hypotenuse
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package ShapesPackage;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle r = new rectangle();
        System.out.println(r.perimeter());
        System.out.println(r.semiPerimeter());
        RightTriangle t = new rightTriangle();
        System.out.println(t.perimeter());  //Fails
    }
}
```

Comment: It does use the `super.semiPermiter() ` method. But that one calls `this.permiter()` in return (which always points to the child-most implementation). And thus starting an infinite loop. Changing the call to `Rectangle.this.permiter()` would solve the problem (as its calling the Rectangles' implemetation specifically)

Comment: You have no bases case in your semi-perimeter method.

Comment: Because rightTriangle overrides perimiter() so triangle.perimeter() --> super(Shapes).semiPermiator() --> triangle.perimiter() which is recursive call with no way to end. Also, please follow standard java naming conventions.  Also, does it make sense for rightTriangle to extend (is-a) rectangle?

Comment: @Sam Orozco: do you mean *base case* ? -it is used for recursive calls! I am trying to avoid all recursive call.

Comment: @Andrew S: You are correct - it is stupid to call a rightTriangle for a form of rectangle, but I was asked to do an exercise that way. I guess the creator was grasping for an example of multiple extends.

Comment: If you have a choice, perhaps as a more realistic example for an inheritance hierarchy could be: `Square` extends `Rectangle`, and `Rectangle` extends `Polygon`, and `Polygon` extends `Shape`.

Comment: To answer the question you asked in several comments on answers, once overridden, the original method is still available, but ***only*** by explicitly calling `super.perimeter()`, and only one level up the hierarchy (if it was overridden at more than one point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method (t.perimeter()) does call `semiPerimeter` method from `Shapes` class, which in turn calls `perimeter` from `rightTriangle` class again and this repeats.

Note that `new rightTriangle()` basically means that `return perimeter() / 2` will invoke `perimeter` method from `rightTriangle` class.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean, that once overridden, the methode will not be accessible!? -and the solution is just not to do a stupid thing like this?

Comment: It means that polymorphic behavior of objects is used. i.e. with late-binding invoking `Shapes.perimeter()` actually invokes `rightTriangle.perimeter()`

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the `super.semiPerimeter()` call not use the `perimeter()` from the rectangle super class?

Because you called it on a `rightTriangle` object which has overridden the  `perimeter()` method. It would make no sense for the call to `perimiter()` to call the `rectangle` class, as it is a `rightTriangle` object. Because of this, the two methods continually call themselves, resulting in a `StackOverflowError`

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean, that once overridden, the methode will not be accessible!? -and the solution is just not to do a stupid thing like this?

Comment: @hpekristiansen No it is still accessible. You are accessing it when you call the method on a `Rectangle`. But since you are calling the method on a `rightTriangle` object, it will call the overridden method from the `rightTriangle` class

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening:

You call `t.perimeter()`, which calls `super.semiPerimeter()` -> `perimeter()` -> `super.semiPerimeter()` etc etc etc.

Sounds like you already know this. I believe that when you extend a class, if you create a method with the same signature as the parent class, you override it, making any calls go to your override method instead of the original. The `perimeter` the abstract class calls is implicitly `this.perimeter`, and what is `this`? It's a `rightTriangle`. So when your abstract class sees `perimeter` it sees the one you made with `rightTriangle`.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean, that once overridden, the methode will not be accessible!? -and the solution is just not to do a stupid thing like this?

Comment: In essence, yes. To be fair, right triangles don't really extend rectangles. I sort of see where your line of thinking was, but if you override a method, you're doing it because you don't want the original method to be called whenever you're interacting with that object. It sounds annoying, but it's part of the design for a reason. On the other hand, if you want to call rectangle.perimeter(), go for it, you'll get the "original" method.

Comment: Incidentally, use CamelCasing when naming objects, it's a good habit to follow standards, and it'll make more experienced programmers much less twitchy :)

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. Just to clarify(and repeat): "You are correct - it is stupid to call a rightTriangle for a form of rectangle, but I was asked to do an exercise that way. I guess the creator was grasping for an example of multiple extends"

Comment: Makes sense, I see where it would be helpful to see how multiple extends work. And it looks like it was successful, you now know one way not to go about it and the reason why, which I'd take as a win. Happy programming!